# Handling several instances of page in Angular + some other stuff

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am building a new application using AngularJS and hereinafter is a simplified description of it.

There is a single **working** page into which I have pills and tabs (using Bootstrap) along with a side-pane from which I can select from a list of page types and, upon selection, a new pill-tab pair is added (the page is `ng-inlcude`-ed). Each sub-page type has its own controller (defined using `ng-controller` at the wrapping `div` of each page).

This is working OK so far.

Now, suppose that in this context there are three main (sub-)pages that can be invoked from the side-pane: Persons, Houses and Cars, each displaying a list of the relevant object types (i.e. persons, houses or cars).

When viewing, say, the list of persons, the user may click on one of the records and a new pill-tab needs to be created with the details of the person.

Here I have two questions:

1. How to I pass to the person-details page the unique ID of the selected person?
2. Since new tabs are created as I select different persons (didn't try this yet), does each INSTANCE of the person-details page have its own context, i.e. `$scope`, or all instances of person-details page share the same `$scope` (note that I'm opening several times the same sub-page with the same controller)?

The bottom line is that I need each instance of any sub-page type to be handled within its own context.

Is this the way AngularJS works or do I need to implement some special tricks?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From what i have read, your business logic is quite advanced. You could achieve this using bare angular, but it will be hard and messy code. I suggest using [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) because

- Your business logic requires nested states (pills and tabs)
- You will produce code that is neat and easy to maintain
- It is according to best practices
- You will be able to handle each page separately

And as to your questions, please refer to the [docs](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/), they will be more useful than mine

Hope, it is useful

Answer (score 0):

Well, the lack of other answers forced me to test things and here are the results/answers for my original questions (posted in case it is of use for others):

1. Since each page has its own controller, I use the `$emit` method with the appropriate parameters to pass information between controllers. It works perfectly for me,
2. Each instance of a page (e.g. when simultaneously looking at the profile of two persons) has its own data context (i.e. `$scope`) and hence there is no cross-talk between the pages.